# Is there a way to store object accessors as variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that I'd like to re-use for different projects where I'm calling similar APIs but the JSON object that I receive might be a little different.  So, when I parse the data, I'd like to have control over what values I access.

For this particular API, the following works:

```
var contractData = theParsedJSONdata.data.items;
```

Going forward the keys `data` and `items` may vary.  Can I use variables to access the object?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
let objectString = ".data.items";
var contractData = theParsedJSONdata + objectString;
```

Example data:

```
    { data: 
   { address: '0x000000000222221111111111',
     updated_at: '2022-02-03T00:30:12.793596926Z',
     next_update_at: '2022-02-03T00:35:12.793597076Z',
     quote_currency: 'USD',
     chain_id: 137,
     items: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`data` and `items` might vary" -- do you mean the keys themselves might be different, or they might have different contents?   I can't tell if you're looking for something like Barmar's suggestion below, or e.g. `theParsedJsonData["data"]["items"]`

Comment: I edited it to answer your question.  They are keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables as object keys with this notation:

```
key1 = "data";
key2 = "items";

obj[key1][key2] // equivalent to obj.data.items
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function.

```
let objectAccessor = obj => obj.data.items;
let contractData = objectAccessor(theParsedJSONdata);
```

You can later reassign `objectAccessor`:

```
objectAccessor = obj => obj.something.thing;
```